# How to start statistical analysis paper

Tags: statistics

I am literally planked ,i dont know what to do. The question is how obesity is linked to hospitalization of an individual.

so we have the data set of subjects according to their gender, if they had less or more BMI result.

"This study aims at assessing how body weight in terms of BMI is related to 
health as measured by hospitalization within the previous year"

what kind of test i should use (i.e. what kind of parameter I am going to test). Clearly I am trying to generate hypothesis and find the correlation. But choosing the appropriate test is the hard part.

Thank you

Comment: Where did this come up?  Is this a homework problem, are you a working on an undergraduate research project, something else?  Just curious.

Comment: its a lab report

Comment: Could you show me a few data ? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to start by imagining what your "statistical methods" section would look like.  And it sounds like your sections would start something like: "In order to examine the implications of obesity for hospitalization, we fit a regression in which number of hospitalizations was the outcome, and obesity was the predictor of interest.  But this begs the question of what sort of regression, what else was included in the regression model, and how.  The answer to the later questions depends, sometimes in rather subtle ways, on considerations that would be specific to your patient population and the manner in which the data were collected.  Here are some considerations that you should probably think about.  Does the amount of time over which patients' hospitalizations would be recorded vary from patient to patient in your study?  Is there any way in which the patient's health status (including obesity related aspects of the health status) would be related to that amount of times?  Is it reasonable to assume that other variables on these subjects more or less completely capture all of the subject-specific sources of variability in hospitalization, or are there "frequent-flyers" and not-so-frequent flyers who, despite having the same values of the other variables would, if you continued to follow them, persist systematically in their propensity for hospitalization?  Do any patients die in the hospital?  How long do patients stay in the hospital - does the amount of time in the hospital substantially curtail the amount of time outside of the hospital in which they could be observed to be readmitted? Et cetera...